# CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR when calling JOCL.org from junit test

Tags: junit, jocl, bazel

I've created a minimal example below, to demonstrate my problem.

```
public class MinimalExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MinimalExample().test();
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        CL.setExceptionsEnabled(true);
        final cl_platform_id[] platforms = new cl_platform_id[1];
        CL.clGetPlatformIDs(platforms.length, platforms, null);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

When I run this as an application, I get the output "Done" as expected.
When I run this as a junit test, I get the following error:

```
1) test(MinimalExample)
org.jocl.CLException: CL_PLATFORM_NOT_FOUND_KHR
    at org.jocl.CL.checkResult(CL.java:787)
    at org.jocl.CL.clGetPlatformIDs(CL.java:2152)
    at MinimalExample.test(MinimalExample.java:15)
```

It really seems that junit is running in some sort of sandbox that cannot access my GPU.  However, I see other people have successfully run JOCL.org code through a junit test.  Example: [Correct way to setup and tear down an openCL unit test in a test suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879642/correct-way-to-setup-and-tear-down-an-opencl-unit-test-in-a-test-suite)  It's not clear to me what is different.  Does anyone know of any sandboxing that could explain this?

Edit: In case it matters,

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
$ uname -a
Linux machine-name 4.2.0-30-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 26 00:58:07 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Mar 15 18:16:36 2016       
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.63     Driver Version: 352.63         | 
<truncated>
```

Edit #2; the saga continues:
I decided the best course of action was to get as close to the problem, manually, as possible.  So I ran it manually.

```
$ java -cp minimal_test.runfiles/external/hamcrest-all/jar/hamcrest-all-1.3.jar:minimal_test.runfiles/external/jocl/jar/jocl-0.2.0-RC00.jar:minimal_test.runfiles/external/junit/jar/junit-4.12.jar:minimal_test.runfiles/external/truth/jar/truth-0.27.jar:minimal_test.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore MinimalExample
JUnit version 4.12
.Done

Time: 0.112

OK (1 test)
```

It works from the command line.  It doesn't work in eclipse.  It doesn't work from bazel.

Edit #3;

I was hoping to wait for full resolution, before closing this, but the bug I filed has yielded a workaround for the bazel use case (but not for eclipse).  Adding `tags = ['local'],` to the BUILD file runs it without a sandbox, allowing the GPU to be contacted.

Comment: I've escalated to a bug: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1049

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with bazel (only stumbled over this because I'm the jocl.org guy), you might consider 1. editing the question to include the `bazel` tag (since it turned out that the question was mainly related to bazel), and 2. answering your own question with the insights from the issue discussion (e.g. it seems that the basic issue was [resolved by passing the `--spawn_strategy=standalone` flag somewhere](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1049#issuecomment-197295301)).

Comment: I've added the bazel workaround to the question; the original issue still happens within eclipse.

Comment: I'll have a closer look at this probably on monday - it should (of course) be possible to run JUnit tests with JOCL from eclipse (although I can only test it on Windows).

Comment: (A minor remark: I tested this, starting the given test as a unit test in Eclipse, and it works for me - if you still encounter this error, and *think* that it is related to JOCL, you might consider [opening an issue](https://github.com/gpu/JOCL/issues), but right now, I have no idea what might cause the platform to *not* be found when run from Eclipse...)

Comment: Thanks for the information, @Marco13; what version of eclipse do you use?

Comment: Luna (4.4), so it's in fact rather old. (I think it should not depend on the version, as the mechanisms of launching haven't really changed in the past XX years...)